# How to get instagram access token for app in sandbox mode

Tags: instagram-api

Currently when using instagram access token by the url "https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[id]&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&response_type=token&scope=public_content" I have such an error

> "This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions."

I observed the internet and found that `scope` query part should be added to the end of API URL. That is how I constructed my url. But as you see it resulted in error.

I tried to find out the reason on app permissions page. There is a button "Start submission". I clicked it and got the list of radio buttons. But when I clicked on " I want to display my Instagram posts on my website." then I got:

> You do not need to submit for review for this use case. If you are a developer and you want to display Instagram content on your website, then you do not need to submit your app for review. By using a client in sandbox mode, you can still access the last 20 media of any sandbox user that grants you permission.

So I finally got lost. Looks like the solution is pretty simple because in instafeed.js plugin no more information is provided. But I can not resolve it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

change your scope to basic should work.
The link has 'public_content'

https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000&response_type=token&scope=basic